# Is there a Drupal tool to aggregate and compress CSS files

Tags: theming

I know that Drupal 7 has settings for *Aggregate and compress CSS files* and *Aggregate Jacascript files* (under `Administration/Configuration/Development/Performance`).

Is there a tool that let me extract the result of this process?

I am using *Sass* and *Compass*, so I guess that to produce an aggregate and compressed `.css`, I could set `output_style = :compressed` in *Compass* and the just concatenate together all the separate `.css` files, but that won't resolve conflicts or combine overlapping CSS selectors.

I wonder if there are some better way to do this, for instance making use of the Drupal built-in tool that apperently is designed specifically for the job.

This is for a Zen sub-theme.  The Zen STARTERKIT produces a lot of CSS-files, and before making this sub-theme generally available, I would like to "clean up" the distribution by consolidating CSS and Javascript into two aggregate and compact files.

(Outside the Drupal universe, [YUI compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) seems to be the most popular tool for this.)

Comment: If you are looking for tool independent from Drupal, it's not a Drupal question.

Comment: Well, I am *not* looking for a tool independent of Drupal. For instance, if there is way (perhaps using *Drush*) to extract the compressed aggregate that Drupal generates, I would be happy to accept that as a solution.

Comment: Drupal compresses and aggregates on the fly, as a rule. That way users of your theme are never left with scrambled, machine-only CSS and are not tied to specific vendor for the lifetime of their website. I guess that's a reason of downvotes. Opensource people doesn't like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css seems like a good place, but I'm no expert.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but Adaptivetheme (and it's sub themes) are designed with SASS and Compass and make use of the built-in compression.  Taking a look at them may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm right in thinking this, but if you're looking for something to reverse the CSS aggregation/compression, but if you are then it doesn't look like there is anything that exists that will give you exactly what was initially compressed. However, the cache Drupal creates is an array that is keyed by the original filename of the cached CSS, so you should be able to find out *WHICH* CSS files are being cached relatively easily (I think the `variable_get('drupal_css_cache_files');` will get the array for you.

If you are looking to mimic what Drupal does when it aggregates and caches your CSS, then take a look at the [`drupal_build_css_cache()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_build_css_cache/7) function (which, as an FYI, is called by [`drupal_aggregate_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_aggregate_css/7)).

As a point of interest, there is also a [`drupal_build_js_cache`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_build_js_cache/7) as you'd expect.

Comment: From what I understood, he wants to compress before publishing, not decompress for edit.

Comment: That's why I added an (albeit short) answer for both situations :-)

Comment: Oh, apparently I missed it somehow. Sorry.

Comment: @Mołot - No worries, I didn't exactly make it obvious :-)